# adding div using javascript that uses angularjs to show data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to add a div to my current website.

The div i would like to add should show some json data using angularjs.

My problem is that it does not look like angularjs is working like its supose to when adding html after the page is rendered.

Here is my test:

```
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script>


    var featureInfoMainDivId = 'FeatureInfoMaster';

    function initAngularDataFeatureInfo() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.textContent =
            'var app = angular.module("featureInfoApp", []); ' +
            'app.controller("featureInfoCtrl", function ($scope) { ' +
                '$scope.firstName = "John" '+
                '$scope.lastName = "Doe" ' +
            '});';
        document.getElementById(featureInfoMainDivId).appendChild(s);
    }

    function addFeatureInfoDiv() {        
        var divMain = document.createElement('div');        
        divMain.setAttribute('id', featureInfoMainDivId);
        divMain.setAttribute('ng-app', "featureInfoApp");
        divMain.setAttribute('ng-controller', "featureInfoCtrl");
        divMain.innerHTML ='<div> {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}</div>';

        document.getElementById('appdiv').appendChild(divMain);

        initAngularDataFeatureInfo();
    }


  </script>


  <body >

    <div id="appdiv"></div>

    <button id="btn_load_grid" onclick="addFeatureInfoDiv();">loaddata</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two semicolons in

```
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
```

If you load the Angular script it looks for ng-app and bootstraps itself. Since you add Angular specific code after the script is loaded, you need to bootstrap Angular manually with:

```
//after initAngularDataFeatureInfo();
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['featureInfoApp']);
});
```

Please remove this line:

```
divMain.setAttribute('ng-app', "featureInfoApp");
```

It is not needed if you bootstrap Angular manually. For further bootstrapping info, see: [Angular bootstrapping documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/guide/bootstrap).

Also: Is there a reason why you are using Angular version 1.2.26? Version 1.5.3 is the latest stable build.

Comment: Great that was it, thanks a lot. I now use version 1.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angular directives. you can create a customer directive which will then feed a template of your liking